# DNS spoofing in Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, dns, spoofing

I'm trying to learn some stuff about DNSspoofing, but it didn't work well for me. Here's what i have done. step 1 : turn my NIC into promisc mode using the following command

```
ifconfig wlan0 promisc
```

step 2 : make a hosts file for dnsspoof named : /usr/share/dsniff/dnsspoof.hosts (this is suggested in the man page of dnsspoof ) here's what's i typed inside the file

```
github.com       192.168.1.102
*.github.com     192.168.1.102
www.github.com  192.168.1.102
```

step 3: run dnsspod with the following command

```
dnsspoof -i wlan0 -f /usr/share/dsniff/dnsspoof.hosts
```

then i get this output :
[image: image from terminal]

everything seems okay to me, but whenever i tried visiting github from my machine or other machine in my network, it didn't go to the given adress 192.168.1.102

Answer (score 1):

Your `dnsspoof.hosts` file is wrong. Read the man page again - it says quite clearly it needs to be in `hosts` format

> Specify the pathname of a file in `hosts`(5) format. Only one hostname allowed per line (no aliases), although hostnames may contain wildcards (such as `*.doubleclick.net`).

Comment: i tried using the hosts file of the system /etc/hosts, but i get an error: INVALID ENTRY

Comment: Then you have an invalid entry. Perhaps if you'd care to share the entry that's at fault...?